# How do I create a SQL query to increase an amount by a percentage?

Tags: sql, database, oracle11g

Hey I'm a novice here and trying to get my head around the simple SQL language. I'm trying to write a query to increase an amount by 7% if the current amount value is less than 140 otherwise by 5%.

```
UPDATE table1
SET amount = amount * 1.07
WHERE amount < 140
OR
SET amount = amount * 1.05
WHERE amount >= 140
```

Is this valid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your statement is not valid SQL syntax.

Use a `case` statement:

```
UPDATE table1
    SET amount = (case when amount < 140 then amount * 1.07
                       else amount * 1.05
                  end);
```